# XML elements to Tuple using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I have created a list ox XElements like :

```
<server>
  <name>serverName</name>
  <ip>123.123.1.2</ip>
</server>
```

with this code:

```
foreach (XElement ele in doc.Root.Descendants("server")){ololo.Add(ele);}
```

How to get a list of `Tuple<name(string),ip(string)>` with LINQ ?

There is similar [XML elements to Tuple using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566581/xml-elements-to-tuple-using-linq) question for VB.Net, but it uses syntax I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I can't understand why the downvote... It's a perfect valid question for someone learning LINQ...

Comment: I agree. Its a valid question for someone learning LINQ.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras valid question showing no research. So downvotes look reasonable to me. The fact that there is no close votes confirm that this question is on topic and there is no immediate duplicates (there are obviously plenty of questions showing how to use LINQ to read XML and convert to objects of all kinds, but not exactly this).

Comment: I've changed title/ added research effort imagining OP have done it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
foreach (XElement ele in doc.Root.Descendants("server")){
    tuples.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(
        ele.Element("name").ToString(),
        ele.Element("ip").ToString()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
var tuples =
    doc.Root.Descendants("server")
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Element("name").Value, x.Element("ip").Value))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep using LINQ!

```
var tuples = doc
    .Root
    .Descendants("server")
    .Select(p => new Tuple<string,string>(
        p.Element("name").Value,
        p.Element("ip").Value));
```